# Browser memory cache getting cleaned after 1 hour in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, caching, iis, memorycache

I am facing an issue with memory cache cleaning up.

I haven't set any maximum age in the cache header. Please find the IIS HTTP response header settings below

[image]

Below is the Httpservice code from the application:

```
 constructor($http: ng.IHttpService,
        $q: ng.IQService, $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService,
        exceptionHandlerSerice: IExceptionHandlerService) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common["X-XSS-Protection"] = "1; mode=block";
        $http.defaults.headers.common["Strict-Transport-Security"] = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
        $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Content-Type-Options"] = "nosniff";
        $http.defaults.headers.common["Cache-control"] = "no-store";
        $http.defaults.headers.common["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
        this.$http = $http;
        this.$q = $q;
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.exceptionHandler = exceptionHandlerSerice;
    }
```

How do I avoid the 1 hour cache cleanup from Chrome?

Comment: Is that 1h after first access that cache is invalidated or 1h unused. How did you find out there is a 1h timeout? Is that a web page or a resource and how do you request it?

Comment: I tried pageSpeedInsight app from chrome store to monitor that app told this is 1 hour caching

Comment: Chrome seems to limit the lifetime of cache entries to 10% of its age as seen by Last-Modified. You can most likely make your documents look older to make them appear static but I think you should not worry too much, in a normal user browser cached resources are overwritten by new ones all the time so 1h is good anyway.